# Make a Python function that will reuse its own (multiple) output

Tags: python, function, return

I want to make a function that will return multiple values. But, I might need to run it multiple times. So I want it to be able to use its own output as arguments.

```py
def return_double_and_triple(n1, n2):
    return n1*2, n2*3

print(return_double_and_triple(4, 5))
```

```
Out[1]: (8, 15)
```

I can't use it twice, however:

```py
print(return_double_and_triple(return_double_and_triple(4, 5)))
```

> TypeError: return_double_and_triple() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n2'
>   Expected output:

```py
Out[1]: (16, 45)
```

I want to be able to call this function on its own output as often as needed. **PLEASE NOTE** that this is a bogus task to understand how it works. Don't suggest alternative ways to return the double and triple of numbers. Thank you.

Comment: Put star `*` next to first function call to unpack parameters: `print(return_double_and_triple(*return_double_and_triple(4, 5)))`

Comment: That's awesome, wow. Why don't you put it as an answer? Don't you want the points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unpack values from function call and use them as function parameters, use star-symbol **`*`** next to first function call:

```
def return_double_and_triple(n1, n2):
    return n1*2, n2*3

print(return_double_and_triple(*return_double_and_triple(4, 5)))
```

Prints:

```
(16, 45)
```